# Roblox Studio Problem I am stuck because i cant get the money when the block goes to the selling area. here is my code

Tags: lua, roblox

I am following a youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTkNHt2CU_k&t=534s
I am stuck because I cant get the money when the block goes to the selling area. here is my code:

```lua
local CashValue = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Values.CashValue

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
    if Hit.Name == "Part" and Hit:FindFirstChild("CashValue")then
        CashValue.Value += Hit:FindFirstChild("CashValue").Value
        Hit:Destroy()
    end
end)
```

to work this out I've tried to check syntax and check case I can post the rest of the code if
needed. this is my first time posting ELI5

Comment: So what isn't actually working? Are you sure that the blocks that are hitting the sell area are named "Part" and have a child in them called "CashValue"?

Comment: yes the blocks are named Part and they have a child named CashValue sorry for the late response